# Laravel local insists PHP 7.1.5 even though WAMP running PHP 5.6.32

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a WAMP installation and selected PHP 5.6.32 as the version to run.
When I run `php artisan serve`, the phpinfo() call returns `PHP 7.1.5 Development Server`

My host has PHP version 5.6.32 installed and I'd like to get Laravel working locally with something other than PHP 7.

What can I do here as the deployment to my host isn't working.

I'm running Laravel version 5.5.32

Comment: When you use WAMP you should not use php artisan serve command! Make a virtual server block inside WAMP and run your app like that. Try this: https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to go down in `Laravel` `Version 5.4` or lower,
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4

** Or you need to upgrade your `WAMP` `PHP` to 7 which is required for `Laravel 5.5`

If you read the docs it will tell you what is required in order to run version of Laravel. It is indicated in to very top of the page under `requirements`

Good luck with the development